# How to schedule wordpress post with python api

Tags: python, wordpress, date, datetime, xml-rpc

i'm trying to post to my wordpress page with python api, publish posts right away working fine, but when im trying to schedule posts it doesn't work, the publish date is :1999/11/30

looks like i don't write the right date pattern.

this is my code:

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts import NewPost
wp = Client('http://url.com/xmlrpc.php', 'username', 'password')
f = open('nm.txt','r')
cn = f.read()
post = WordPressPost()
post.title = "time stamp test"
post.content = cn
post.post_status = 'future'
post.date = '2012-02-14T11:22:34.593750Z'; 

wp.call(NewPost(post))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use UTC format for the date attribute. For example

```
from datetime import datetime
post.title = "woohhh!!!"
post.content = "blah blah blah"
post.date = datetime(2013, 11, 14, 20, 34, 2, 860000)
post.post_status = 'publish'
```

Comment: for some reason it's not working anymore, the post schedule to 1970/01/01.
post.date = datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 15, 18, 7, 27)
post.post_status = 'publish'
wp.call(NewPost(post))